# Tuple element to its own tuple and append item

Tags: python

I want to do this:

```
[("item1", "item2"), ("item3", "item4")]
# ->
[("item1", ("item2", True)), ("item3", ("item4", True))]
```

How can I do this? I have a list of tuples, and the second element in each tuple needs to be it's own tuple, and I need to append an element to the sub tuple.

Answer (score 3):

an option is to use a list-comprehension:

```
lst = [("item1", "item2"), ("item3", "item4")]
res = [(a, (b, True)) for a, b in lst]
print(res)  # [("item1", ("item2", True)), ("item3", ("item4", True))]
```

Comment: This answer unpacks the elements of lst. This is smart.

Comment: i prefer this to indexing later (as you did). but that's ok as well! +1

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer

```py
lst = [("item1", "item2"), ("item3", "item4")]

new_lst = []

for f,s in lst:
    new_lst.append((f, (s, True)))
print(new_lst)
```

OUTPUT

```py
[("item1", ("item2", True)), ("item3", ("item4", True))]
```

**USING LIST COMPREHENSION**

```py
lst = [("item1", "item2"), ("item3", "item4")]
new_lst = [(f, (s, True)) for f,s in lst]

print(new_lst)
```

OUTPUT

```py
[("item1", ("item2", True)), ("item3", ("item4", True))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to complete this:

```
material = [("item1", "item2"), ("item3", "item4")]
# ->
expected = [("item1", ("item2", True)), ("item3", ("item4", True))]

actual = [(elt[0], (elt[1], True)) for elt in material]
assert actual == expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this would be to use the [`map`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp) function.

This is what you could do:

```
def map_func(item):
    return (item[0], (item[1], True))

array = [("item1", "item2"), ("item3", "item4")]
new_array = list(map(map_func, array))

print(new_array) # [('item1', ('item2', True)), ('item3', ('item4', True))]
```

You could use [`lambda`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) too (in order to shorten the code), like so:

```
new_array = list(map(lambda item: (item[0], (item[1], True)), array))
```